# Graph Database techniques: discovering degrees of congruence

Tags: neo4j, pattern-matching, graph-databases

Assume we have a collection of 100,000 people who each have a list of attributes such as:

```
height: "between 130 and 140 cm"
eyecolor: "blue"
age_rangee: "16-18"
favorite_music_type: "jazz"
home_city: "NYC"
owns_a_boat: "no"
preferred_flower: "hyacinth"
bathing_frequency_per_month: 60
car_type: "minivan"
house_type: "apartment"
wears_jeans: "often"
wears_sandals: "never"
wears_boots: "sometimes"
```

The set of attributes may vary somewhat from person to person. The number of attributes can change, and the types of attributes may change. And of course, the values of the attributes may change.However, given one individual, we assume there is some overlap of his attributes with those a number of people in our collection.

The question I have is:  "What is the best way of expressing these various 
attributes in a graph database such that I can most quickly select a group of say 50 people whose attributes most similarly match that of a particular individual, and order them from best-match to worst-match"

Thanks Kenny,

In your example Cypher query, do I understand that each feature node contains a key:value 
pair that identifies the attribute and it's corresponding value?

Here is a somewhat more complex congruence matching problem.

Assume we have a feature set, (A, B, C, D, E, F), and 100,000 
people who have preferences that match to some degree this preference set.
But each feature, not only may they have a preference, but they may have NO preference.

For example Lena's preferences are, (A, B, C, X, Y, Z), and
Robert's preferences are, (A, B, C, _, _, *), (where underbar, (*), signifies that any choice is OK)

We would like to rate Robert higher than Lena in terms of preference matching because while
he and Lena have the same number of matching preferences, Robert has fewer mis-matching preferences

Here is a more concrete example:

Lets say we have 100,000 people who are interested in cars, and we know what features of cars are important to them. 
We have, say, 10 cars, with various features and we want to select a group of say, 50 people, whose desired-car-features best
match each of the 10 cars.

Some people will have no preference about a subset all car features. 
For example Lester has no preference with respect to transmission, either 'automatic' or 'manual', would be just fine, 
and Rebecca has no preference with respect to 'color', 'power_windows', and 'power_door_locks'. Any color would be fine, and 
she does not care if the car has power windows and door locks.

So for example, here is a car with a defined set of features

`engine: '4cylinder'
transmission: 'automatic'
color: 'dark blue'
size: 'subcompact'
age: 'less than 4 years'
power_windows: 'yes'
power_door_locks: 'yes'
average_gas_milage: 'greater than 30mpg'`

And here we have two individuals, Lester, and Rebecca who have indicated features that are important to them:

Lester:
`engine: '4cylinder'
color: 'dark blue'
size: 'subcompact'
age: 'less than 4 years'
power_windows: 'yes'
power_door_locks: 'yes'
average_gas_milage: 'greater than 30mpg'`

Rebecca:
`engine: '4cylinder'
transmission: 'automatic'
size: 'subcompact'
age: 'less than 4 years'
average_gas_milage: 'greater than 30mpg'`

So how can we best select and order a group of 50 people whose feature-preferences best match each car?
In this case we want the people with the maximal matching-feature preferences ranked first,
but we also want to include those people who would be happy with any value of particular attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Great question. First, I recommend taking the free online training course that masterfully introduces you to the basic concepts behind Neo4j and Cypher query language: http://www.neo4j.org/training

Your problem is a simple data modeling exercise I'm happy to walk you through. As you model data as a graph, certain attributes or properties of a class, for instance a person, can be represented themselves as a node.

By looking at some sample data for the class `person`, you will of course notice some redundancies in the value of the properties. These overlaps allow us to select on that class and group results by a shared property. That's fairly easy to do in most databases. What Neo4j lets you do is to take an arbitrary set of features belonging to a person and to then select all similar people based on those shared features.

```
MATCH (john:Person {name: "John Doe"})-[:HAS_FEATURE]->(feature),
      (feature)<-[:HAS_FEATURE]-(people)
WITH john, count(DISTINCT feature) as feature_count, people
RETURN john.name, people.name, feature_count
ORDER BY feature_count DESC
```

This query finds a person named `John Doe` and all the features that belong to him. Each feature is a node that represents a value that can be attributed to a person. Each feature is unique, as a single node, and groups people together.

The query then finds all `people` who share a `feature` with `john`. Then in the `WITH` clause, the query counts the features that `john` shares with each person. Finally, the query returns `john`'s name, the name of the person he shares features with and the count of the number of features they share. Then the query is ordered by `feature_count` descending.

This returns back the people who share the most features with John Doe.

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at the ["Matches are the new Hotness"](http://maxdemarzi.com/2012/10/18/matches-are-the-new-hotness/) and ["Match Making with Neo4j"](http://maxdemarzi.com/2013/04/19/match-making-with-neo4j/) blog posts for examples of how to connect partial subgraphs of nodes to each other.

```
START me=node:users_index(name={user})
MATCH skills<-[:has]-me-[:lives_in]->city<-[:in_location]-job-[:requires]->requirements
WHERE me-[:has]->()<-[:requires]-job
WITH DISTINCT city.name AS city_name, 
   job.name AS job_name,
   LENGTH(me-[:has]->()<-[:requires]-job) AS matching_skills,
   LENGTH(job-[:requires]->()) AS job_requires,
   COLLECT(DISTINCT requirements.name) AS req_names, 
   COLLECT(DISTINCT skills.name) AS skill_names
RETURN city_name, job_name, 
FILTER(name IN req_names WHERE NOT name IN skill_names) AS missing
ORDER BY matching_skills / job_requires DESC, job_requires
LIMIT 10
```

and

```
START me=node:users_index(name={user})
MATCH me-[:lives_in]->city<-[:lives_in]-person
WHERE me.orientation = person.orientation AND
((me.gender <> person.gender AND me.orientation = "straight") OR
 (me.gender = person.gender AND me.orientation = "gay")) AND
  me-[:wants]->()<-[:has]-person AND
  me-[:has]->()<-[:wants]-person 
WITH DISTINCT city.name AS city_name, person, me
MATCH  me-[:wants]->attributes<-[:has]-person-[:wants]->requirements<-[:has]-me
RETURN city_name, person.name AS person_name,
   COLLECT(attributes.name) AS my_interests,
   COLLECT(requirements.name) AS their_interests,
   COUNT(attributes) AS matching_wants, 
  COUNT(requirements) AS matching_has
ORDER BY matching_wants / (1.0 / matching_has) DESC
LIMIT 10
```